# Intel VT-x not working on Dell Precision M4400 (P8600 processor)

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-vista, dell, 64-bit

I have a Dell Precision Laptop model M4400 with an Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 processor.  In the BIOS, there are several options for enabling virtualization technology (VT-x).  I've toggled all of these options ON.  My problem is that neither Virtual PC 2007 nor Sun's VirtualBox will allow me to use VT-x on this system.

Host OS:  Windows Vista Enterprise SP1 (**64-bit**)

Thanks for any information or insight you can provide.  For the more technical folks, here's the VirtualBox log file that is generated with I boot an Ubuntu guest:

```
00:00:01.134 VirtualBox 2.2.2 r46594 win.amd64 (Apr 27 2009 18:40:08) release log
00:00:01.134 Log opened 2009-06-15T19:10:25.317308400Z
00:00:01.134 OS Product: Windows Vista Enterprise Edition
00:00:01.134 OS Release: 6.0.6001
00:00:01.134 OS Service Pack: 1
00:00:01.134 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:01.215 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (C:\PROGRA~1\Sun\XVMVIR~1/VMMR0.r0) at 0xfffffa800c054080 - ModuleInit at fffffa800c062bb0 and ModuleTerm at fffffa800c062c30
00:00:01.215 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at fffffa800c0638b0, VMMR0EntryFast at fffffa800c062e30 and VMMR0EntryInt at fffffa800c062e20
00:00:01.215 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\PROGRA~1\Sun\XVMVIR~1/VMMR0.r0=0xfffffa800c054080
00:00:01.596 VBoxSharedClipboard mode: Bidirectional
00:00:01.965 OpenGL Warning: Render SPU: WGL wants these visual capabilities: RGB, Doublebuffer, Z
00:00:02.617 OpenGL Warning: Render SPU: WGL chose these visual capabilities: RGB, Doublebuffer, Z, Accum
00:00:02.617 OpenGL Warning: Render SPU: WGL wants these visual capabilities: RGB, Doublebuffer, Z
00:00:02.634 OpenGL Warning: Render SPU: WGL chose these visual capabilities: RGB, Doublebuffer, Z, Accum
00:00:03.008 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VENDOR:   NVIDIA Corporation
00:00:03.008 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_RENDERER: Quadro FX 770M/PCI/SSE2
00:00:03.008 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VERSION:  2.1.2
00:00:03.015 Shared crOpenGL service loaded.
00:00:03.119 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
00:00:03.119 pRoot=0000000003dd1780:{/}
00:00:03.119 [/] (level 0)
00:00:03.119   Name               <string>  = "Ubuntu" (cch=7)
00:00:03.119   UUID               <bytes>   = "4c 16 90 23 f4 60 c0 47 9d 83 67 c2 3c 4d a6 bb" (cb=16)
00:00:03.119   RamSize            <integer> = 0x0000000040000000 (1073741824)
00:00:03.119   RamHoleSize        <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536870912)
00:00:03.119   NumCPUs            <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   TimerMillies       <integer> = 0x000000000000000a (10)
00:00:03.119   RawR3Enabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   RawR0Enabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   PATMEnabled        <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   CSAMEnabled        <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   HwVirtExtForced    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.119   EnableNestedPaging <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119   EnableVPID         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.119   EnablePAE          <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/HWVirtExt/] (level 1)
00:00:03.119   Enabled <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/PDM/] (level 1)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/PDM/Drivers/] (level 2)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/PDM/Drivers/VBoxC/] (level 3)
00:00:03.119   Path <string>  = "VBoxC" (cch=6)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/] (level 1)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/pcarch/] (level 2)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/pcarch/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.119   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/pcarch/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/pcbios/] (level 2)
00:00:03.119 
00:00:03.119 [/Devices/pcbios/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.120   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120   RamSize                <integer> = 0x0000000040000000 (1073741824)
00:00:03.120   RamHoleSize            <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536870912)
00:00:03.120   NumCPUs                <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120   HardDiskDevice         <string>  = "piix3ide" (cch=9)
00:00:03.120   FloppyDevice           <string>  = "i82078" (cch=7)
00:00:03.120   IOAPIC                 <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.120   PXEDebug               <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.120   UUID                   <bytes>   = "4c 16 90 23 f4 60 c0 47 9d 83 67 c2 3c 4d a6 bb" (cb=16)
00:00:03.120   BootDevice0            <string>  = "FLOPPY" (cch=7)
00:00:03.120   BootDevice1            <string>  = "DVD" (cch=4)
00:00:03.120   BootDevice2            <string>  = "IDE" (cch=4)
00:00:03.120   BootDevice3            <string>  = "NONE" (cch=5)
00:00:03.120   SataHardDiskDevice     <string>  = "ahci" (cch=5)
00:00:03.120   SataPrimaryMasterLUN   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.120   SataPrimarySlaveLUN    <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120   SataSecondaryMasterLUN <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:03.120   SataSecondarySlaveLUN  <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/8237A/] (level 2)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/8237A/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.120   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pci/] (level 2)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.120   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120   IOAPIC <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/] (level 2)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.120   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120   Driver <string>  = "KeyboardQueue" (cch=14)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.120   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000040 (64)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:03.120   Driver <string>  = "MainKeyboard" (cch=13)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:03.120   Object <integer> = 0x0000000003d2e930 (64153904)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120   Driver <string>  = "MouseQueue" (cch=11)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.120   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000080 (128)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:03.120   Driver <string>  = "MainMouse" (cch=10)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:03.120   Object <integer> = 0x0000000003dd9560 (64853344)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/i82078/] (level 2)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/i82078/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.120   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.120 
00:00:03.120 [/Devices/i82078/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.120   IRQ       <integer> = 0x0000000000000006 (6)
00:00:03.120   DMA       <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:03.120   MemMapped <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.120   IOBase    <integer> = 0x00000000000003f0 (1008)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i82078/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i82078/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.121   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd90f0 (64852208)
00:00:03.121   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i82078/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121   Driver <string>  = "Block" (cch=6)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i82078/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.121   Type      <string>  = "Floppy 1.44" (cch=12)
00:00:03.121   Mountable <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/acpi/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/acpi/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000007 (7)
00:00:03.121   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/acpi/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121   RamSize     <integer> = 0x0000000040000000 (1073741824)
00:00:03.121   RamHoleSize <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536870912)
00:00:03.121   NumCPUs     <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121   IOAPIC      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121   FdcEnabled  <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121   Driver <string>  = "ACPIHost" (cch=9)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8254/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8254/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8254/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8259/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8259/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/i8259/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/apic/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/apic/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/apic/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121   IOAPIC  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121   NumCPUs <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/mc146818/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/mc146818/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/mc146818/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/vga/] (level 2)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/vga/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.121   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.121   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:03.121   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.121 
00:00:03.121 [/Devices/vga/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   VRamSize         <integer> = 0x0000000004000000 (67108864)
00:00:03.122   FadeIn           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   FadeOut          <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   LogoTime         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122   LogoFile         <string>  = "" (cch=1)
00:00:03.122   ShowBootMenu     <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:03.122   CustomVideoModes <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122   HeightReduction  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "MainDisplay" (cch=12)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   Object <integer> = 0x0000000003dd9680 (64853632)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/] (level 2)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.122   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Type <string>  = "PIIX4" (cch=6)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd9100 (64852224)
00:00:03.122   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#2/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "Block" (cch=6)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#2/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   Type      <string>  = "DVD" (cch=4)
00:00:03.122   Mountable <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/] (level 2)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.122   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x000000000000000d (13)
00:00:03.122   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   PortCount       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   PrimaryMaster   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122   PrimarySlave    <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.122   SecondaryMaster <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:03.122   SecondarySlave  <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd9120 (64852256)
00:00:03.122   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "Block" (cch=6)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   Type      <string>  = "HardDisk" (cch=9)
00:00:03.122   Mountable <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:03.122   Driver <string>  = "VD" (cch=3)
00:00:03.122 
00:00:03.122 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:03.123   Path   <string>  = "C:\Users\scotta\.VirtualBox\HardDisks\Ubuntu.vdi" (cch=49)
00:00:03.123   Format <string>  = "VDI" (cch=4)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/] (level 2)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.123   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.123   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:03.123   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.123   Am79C973       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.123   MAC            <bytes>   = "08 00 27 34 fc 7c" (cb=6)
00:00:03.123   CableConnected <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.123   LineSpeed      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.123   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.123   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd9290 (64852624)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.123   Driver <string>  = "IntNet" (cch=7)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.123   Trunk     <string>  = "\DEVICE\{EC7D0D54-C9A8-40C3-943C-3C2310B67D04}" (cch=47)
00:00:03.123   TrunkType <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:03.123   Network   <string>  = "HostInterfaceNetworking-Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection" (cch=68)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/e1000/] (level 2)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/serial/] (level 2)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/parallel/] (level 2)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/VMMDev/] (level 2)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.123   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.123   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000004 (4)
00:00:03.123   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.123   Driver <string>  = "MainVMMDev" (cch=11)
00:00:03.123 
00:00:03.123 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.124   Object <integer> = 0x0000000003dd7dd0 (64847312)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.124   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd92d0 (64852688)
00:00:03.124   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.124   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/AudioSniffer/] (level 2)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/AudioSniffer/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/AudioSniffer/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/AudioSniffer/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124   Driver <string>  = "MainAudioSniffer" (cch=17)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/AudioSniffer/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.124   Object <integer> = 0x0000000003d28bf0 (64130032)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/ichac97/] (level 2)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/ichac97/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.124   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.124   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000005 (5)
00:00:03.124   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/ichac97/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/ichac97/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124   Driver <string>  = "AUDIO" (cch=6)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/ichac97/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.124   AudioDriver <string>  = "dsound" (cch=7)
00:00:03.124   StreamName  <string>  = "Ubuntu" (cch=7)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/] (level 2)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.124   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.124   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000006 (6)
00:00:03.124   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124   Driver <string>  = "VUSBRootHub" (cch=12)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.124   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.124 
00:00:03.124 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.125   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd92d8 (64852696)
00:00:03.125   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/] (level 2)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:03.125   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:03.125   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x000000000000000b (11)
00:00:03.125   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:03.125   Driver <string>  = "VUSBRootHub" (cch=12)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:03.125   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cch=11)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:03.125   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000003dd92e0 (64852704)
00:00:03.125   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 [/TM/] (level 1)
00:00:03.125   UTCOffset <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:03.125 
00:00:03.125 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************
00:00:03.125 MM: cbHyperHeap=0x140000 (1310720)
00:00:03.130 CPUMSetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled PAE
00:00:03.130 Logical host processors: 2, processor active mask: 0000000000000003
00:00:03.130 ************************* CPUID dump ************************
00:00:03.130          RAW Standard CPUIDs
00:00:03.130      Function  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000000  00000002 756e6547 6c65746e 49656e69
00:00:03.130 Hst:           0000000d 756e6547 6c65746e 49656e69
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000001  0001067a 00000800 00000009 078bf1ff
00:00:03.130 Hst:           0001067a 01020800 0408e3fd bfebfbff
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000002  05b0b101 005657f0 00000000 2cb43048
00:00:03.130 Hst:           05b0b101 005657f0 00000000 2cb43048
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000003  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000004  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 00000005  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000040 00000040 00000003 03122220
00:00:03.130 Name:                            GenuineIntel
00:00:03.130 Supports:                        0-2
00:00:03.130 Family:                          6     Extended: 0     Effective: 6
00:00:03.130 Model:                           7     Extended: 1     Effective: 23
00:00:03.130 Stepping:                        10
00:00:03.130 APIC ID:                         0x00
00:00:03.130 Logical CPUs:                    0
00:00:03.130 CLFLUSH Size:                    8
00:00:03.130 Brand ID:                        0x00
00:00:03.130 Mnemonic - Description                 = guest (host)
00:00:03.130 FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                  = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 VME - Virtual 8086 Mode Enhancements   = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 DE - Debugging extensions              = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PSE - Page Size Extension              = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 TSC - Time Stamp Counter               = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 MSR - Model Specific Registers         = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PAE - Physical Address Extension       = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 MCE - Machine Check Exception          = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 CX8 - CMPXCHG8B instruction            = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 APIC - APIC On-Chip                    = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0 (0)
00:00:03.130 SEP - SYSENTER and SYSEXIT             = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 MTRR - Memory Type Range Registers     = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PGE - PTE Global Bit                   = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 MCA - Machine Check Architecture       = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 CMOV - Conditional Move Instructions   = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PAT - Page Attribute Table             = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PSE-36 - 36-bit Page Size Extention    = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 PSN - Processor Serial Number          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.130 CLFSH - CLFLUSH Instruction.           = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0 (0)
00:00:03.130 DS - Debug Store                       = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 ACPI - Thermal Mon. & Soft. Clock Ctrl.= 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 MMX - Intel MMX Technology             = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 FXSR - FXSAVE and FXRSTOR Instructions = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 SSE - SSE Support                      = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 SSE2 - SSE2 Support                    = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 SS - Self Snoop                        = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 HTT - Hyper-Threading Technolog        = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 TM - Thermal Monitor                   = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 30 - Reserved                          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.130 PBE - Pending Break Enable             = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Supports SSE3 or not                   = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0 (2)
00:00:03.130 Supports MONITOR/MWAIT                 = 1 (1)
00:00:03.130 CPL-DS - CPL Qualified Debug Store     = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 VMX - Virtual Machine Technology       = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Enhanced SpeedStep Technology          = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Terminal Monitor 2                     = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Supports Supplemental SSE3 or not      = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 L1 Context ID                          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0x0 (0x0)
00:00:03.130 CMPXCHG16B                             = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 xTPR Update Control                    = 0 (1)
00:00:03.130 Reserved                               = 0x0 (0x811)
00:00:03.130 
00:00:03.130          RAW Extended CPUIDs
00:00:03.130      Function  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000000  80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000001  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000001 20100800
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000002  65746e49 2952286c 726f4320 4d542865
00:00:03.130 Hst:           65746e49 2952286c 726f4320 4d542865
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000003  44203229 43206f75 20205550 50202020
00:00:03.130 Hst:           44203229 43206f75 20205550 50202020
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000004  30303638 20402020 30342e32 007a4847
00:00:03.130 Hst:           30303638 20402020 30342e32 007a4847
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000005  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000006  00000000 00000000 0c006040 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 0c006040 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000007  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000008  00003024 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00003024 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Gst: 80000009  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000*
00:00:03.130 Hst:           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00:00:03.130 Ext Name:                        
00:00:03.130 Ext Supports:                    0x80000000-0x80000008
00:00:03.130 Family:                          0     Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:03.130 Model:                           0     Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:03.130 Stepping:                        0
00:00:03.130 Brand ID:                        0x000
00:00:03.130 Mnemonic - Description                 = guest (host)
00:00:03.131 FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                  = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 VME - Virtual 8086 Mode Enhancements   = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 DE - Debugging extensions              = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 PSE - Page Size Extension              = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 TSC - Time Stamp Counter               = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 MSR - K86 Model Specific Registers     = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 PAE - Physical Address Extension       = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 MCE - Machine Check Exception          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 CX8 - CMPXCHG8B instruction            = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 APIC - APIC On-Chip                    = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 10 - Reserved                          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 SEP - SYSCALL and SYSRET               = 0 (1)
00:00:03.131 MTRR - Memory Type Range Registers     = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 PGE - PTE Global Bit                   = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 MCA - Machine Check Architecture       = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 CMOV - Conditional Move Instructions   = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 PAT - Page Attribute Table             = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 PSE-36 - 36-bit Page Size Extention    = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 18 - Reserved                          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 19 - Reserved                          = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 NX - No-Execute Page Protection        = 0 (1)
00:00:03.131 DS - Debug Store                       = 0 (0)
00:00:03.131 AXMMX - AMD Extensions t
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've uncovered the mystery.  In the BIOS for the M4400, there are 3 options for virtualization.  One of those options is called "Trusted Execution" which I had turned on.  Even though my TPM was enabled, for some reason this setting was causing the system to not recognize VT-x.  Once I disabled "Trusted Execution" in my BIOS under the "Virtualization" section, I was able to use VT-x in Virtual PC and Sun xVM VirtualBox

Comment: I had the same problem on my M2400 -- and the same solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) should tell you whether hardware virtualization is properly enabled or not.

Also, are you running the latest BIOS? There have been some Dell models that had VT-X processors, but it didn't work until the latest BIOS software was applied.

Comment: +1 for the Securable link.  According to Securable, my system does support VT-x.  I'm checking into the BIOS details now...

Comment: Unfortunately, updating to the latest BIOS did not resolve this issue.  I double-checked after the BIOS update that VT-x was enabled, and I still get no results from VirtualBox or VirtualPC 2007.  SecureAble still shows that everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call Dell.  That's not the answer you're looking for, but they'll be able to track it down if you have a hardware problem.  Everything in that laptop should let you do VT-x without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Power down the computer.  Ideally I also remove the power cord to completely power down the mother board.  Then power it back on.

The VT setting remains the same once the CPU is powered on, regardless of what the BIOS is set to.  You need to remove the power to release the lock and have the new setting take effect.

Comment: I'm going to try this Monday.  It's my work laptop, and it occurs to me that it's always been plugged in (or at least on stand-by) since I changed this setting.

Comment: Should work, my think pad was similiar.  I pulled the battery to be sure to was totally powered down.

Comment: This did not work :(  I even removed the battery.

Comment: That sucks, I'd say you're at the call Dell part.  If they give you any BS about not able to support you just ask for the tech's manager.  I've done that with them a couple of times, at the very least you can let your frustrations out on them if they don't/can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that SpaceManSpiff's solution of powering down completely solved the problem.  I have a Dell E6400 with an Intel Core Duo P9500.

Steps I followed:

- Installed Virtualbox 3.1.0 host Windows Vista, Guest Ubuntu
- Virtual Box go to Settings | System | Processors ; set it to 2 processors
- Start the machine
- got the "VT-x is not available"
- rebooted and F2 to get to bios, enabled
- got the "VT-x is not available"
- used "securable.exe" from http://www.grc.com/SecurityNow.htm and found out VT-x was still disabled
- pulled out hear, searched alot, found SpaceManSpiff's posting
- powered down and pulled out battery (Not sure if the battery made any difference)
- powered up and it works now!

I'm so glad to finally have two processors for my virtual machine!

Answer (score 0):

It works in almost the same way as described by Sanmi on HP 6530b with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T9600 @ 2.80GHz. It's very important to shutdown your computer after the BIOS VT change.

SecurAble shows "Locked On" but it (VT-x) works, especially under SUN VirtualBox-3.1.2-56127-Win.

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,

Boyan Boychev, Bulgaria